# C++ regex_match match_continuous flag doesn't match beginning sub-string

Tags: c++, regex

I had been rumbling with regex_match with the following example

```
string text("*  @file  my_file.c");
regex exp("\\s*\\*\\s*@file")

if(regex_match(text,exp,regex_constants::match_continuous))
    //This doesn't work
```

I know that *regex_match* try to match whole text with regex expression but as far as I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) *match_continuous* flag supposed to accept sub-strings that start at the beginning of the text. But my luck didn't go well so I had to convert my solution to this

```
string text("*  @file  my_file.c");
regex exp("^\\s*\\*\\s*@file")

if(regex_search(text,exp))
    //This time works
```

I would like to ask that what was I doing wrong in the first example. My environment is VS2010.

Comment: It may be a bug, I remember seeing something somewhat similar a year or two ago.

Comment: So the use of regex_constants::match_continuous seems right isn't it? Thought I may be missing something here.

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure so I won't post it as an answer. I might be missing something too.

Comment: `match_continuous` doesn't alter the fact that the whole sequence must match the expression for `regex_match` to succeed. The standard explicitly requires that `m.suffix` be an empty range as a postcondition of `regex_match` call (where `m` is a `match_results` instance, implied in your case). As far as I can tell, `match_continuous` is meaningless and redundant when used with `regex_match`.

Comment: You are saying that it has been left there to be compliant with the _regex_constants::match_flag_type_ in order to prevent a second domain of flags?

Answer (score 3):

`match_continous` works with `regex_search`.

E.g.

```
std::regex_search(text, exp, std::regex_constants::match_continuous)
```